# Not able to Iterate List contains Hibernate query result in sruts 2 action?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

i am not able to iterate list of results from HQL. i am using foreach loop. but loop is not executing in my struts action method named getCompanyies(). i am getting size of list in console but for loop is skiped may be because i am not getting 'inside for' message in console. i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException exception

my Action Code is:-

```
public String getCompanies(){
    try{
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("inside get companies");
    List<Company> companies= session.createQuery("select companyID,companyName from Company").list();
    System.out.println(companies.size());
    for(Company obj : companies) {
        System.out.println("inside for");
        System.out.println(obj.getCompanyID());
    }
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.close();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the object in the companies `List` are not of type `Company` (you may have a warning on the assignement of your list) because you are selecting companyID,companyName in your `HQL` query.

What can quickly help you out of there is to just rewrite your query :

```
List<Company> companies= session.createQuery("from Company").list();
```

Because your first query will return an array of object containing the two properties you requested. (you will obtain a `List<Object[]>` and you will have to get the value from this array), so your code would look like :

```
List<Object[]> companies= session.createQuery("select companyID,companyName from Company").list();
```

And you will have to get the value on each array of your result list.

Comment: but how to iterate this array